# Rails 3.2.11 First Test App -- Template is Missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie in ruby on rails Web-Programming. Today I tried to set up Ruby programming language and also the Rails framework. Ruby works properly, I made a first Test-Class Successfull. Only setting up my Rails framework prepares me some problem.

I made a `test_app` and i tried to run it.

```
rails new test_app
rails s
```

I realized that the the routes was commented in `routes.rb` and I uncommented it. 
I changed `#root :to => 'welcome#index'` to `root :to => 'welcome#index'`.

I also realized that I do not had a controller for the page `welcome/index` and i created it
with `rails g controller Welcome index`.

But It do not work yet? Anybody an idea?

```
Template is missing
Missing template welcome/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "D:/Davide Giunta/Development/workspace[ruby]/test_app/app/views"

Ruby Version: 1.9.3p368
Gem Version: 1.8.24
Rails Version: 3.2.11
```

Answer (score 3):

`rails g controller` will only create the controller part, you also need to create a corresponding view file, in this case, you want `app/views/welcome/index.html.erb`

Using `scaffold` (only while learning), or `resource` for your generator might be faster. (I usually create them all by hand these days)

Comment: Hello Jim, the view part was with controller also created. In the same path you mentioned. That's my problem i possess a view, rails looks in the right folder, the view folder. The problem is my view is in the subfolder welcome (also test_app/app/views/welcome). Why rails creates me a folder welcome, when it is not needed?!

Comment: In your comment to @fillky, you mention having plural paths `app/views/welcomes`, `welcomes_controller.rb`, etc. That is not the same as `app/views/welcome` and `welcome_controller.rb`. If you do have files in the right place (`welcome` not `welcomes`), then I cannot really help from here, and asking someone on IRC or going through tutorials and coming back might work better.

Comment: I know that they don't are in the right place. But rails generated that, and so that should be right, normaly. No prob, thanks for your answers I will try it until it works!

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Jim Deville is correct. You need to create corresponding view file of your controller's action (action_name.html.erb) and place it to views dir under subdirectory named like your controller.

See basics of Rails here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

When you want to create action with controller, view and model you should use `rails g scaffold SomeName` also see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding.

Comment: Hello Fillky, thanks for your answer. But like i commented in the post of Jim, it do not work also with scaffold. All files have been generated in the right way I belive 
The file in app/views/welcomes are
 _form.hmtl.erb
 edit.html.erb
 index.html.erb
 new.html.erb
 show.html.erb

in app/controlles I have the file welcomes_controller.rb
in app/helpers I have the file welcomes_helper.rb
and in app/models I have the file welcome.rb

???

Do you have an idea who is the problem?